# Is it possible to store event.target in a global variable without the need for the object to have an id attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code :

```
var cible;

function 1() {
    cible = $(e.target).closest("tr");
}

function 2() {
    $(cible).find(".class");
}
```

I need to store the event.target in a variable but i'm not able to use id attribute...

In other words : is there a "ID" of the element i can store in a variable but that is not an actual id="" or class=""?

What do you advise ?

Comment: The question is why do you need to do this, the `event.target` is only available when someone actually triggers the event handler, so there's no need to store it beyond the callback for the event

Comment: You can pass `cible` as parameter to `2()`. `function 2(el){ $(eq).find(".class");}`

Comment: You don't need an ID to store a click target. When you use event.target. The target node is passed to the `cible` variable the moment you click the target. 

By referring to `cible`, you are referring to the object you last clicked. If the `cible` var sits in the global scope, that object will be accessible through `cible` unless a different object is clicked. If you want to store all objects clicked, create an array and push `cible` into the array each time you click on something. You will then have an array of targets that you can access by array position.

Comment: Yes ! Thank you !! That is the solution i looked for...It mean that all elements have another way than IDs to be stored !! Thanks a lot !